# Running psql on Amazon Django Lightsail

Tags: django, linux, postgresql, psql, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to run "psql" on Amazon Lightsail, Django instance.

```
psql
Password for user bitnami: 
psql.bin: FATAL:  password authentication failed fo
r user "bitnami"
```

It doesn't work even though I got bitnami's password through

```
cat bitnami_application_password
```

Upon further review, it seems that there are multiple types of psql installed on the Amazon Lightsail instance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

then when asking for password put the password came from bitnami_application_password